# Algorithm to compute portfolio excess returns index g, per different investment proportion x in r

Tags: r, algorithm, indexing, portfolio

Suppose two assets in portfolio: asset 1, asset 2, and have 4 observations of return rates per three different proportions of investment on asset1.

```
      x <- c(0.1, 0.4, 0.8)                # investment weight for asset1
      l <- list(a=1:4, b=3:7, c=5:9)     # excess (portfolio) return per x 
                                         # just made up
```

Excess returns index g can be computed by this (t is time: 1,..,T):
          g1 = 100`enter code here`
          gt = g(t-1) * (1 + excess return(t))

I have to let a function compute the excess returns index g per weight x.
What I did was:

```
      l2<-lapply(l, function(x) x+1)  

      l3 <- vector("list", 3)

      g<-c(100)
      for(i in 1:3){
        for(j in 1:3){

          k<-2
          while(k<-4){

            g<-c(g, (g[k]*l2[[i]][j]))

            l3[[i]]<- g    
            k<-k+1
          }

        }
  }
```

I need to use an algorithm in stead of these heavy burdened loops. I couldn't even get an solution only for this small data on my laptop. I need to compute a g value for each case per x in which to eventually compute the compounded annual growth rate, CAGR through this value (gT/g1) for each different proportion of investment in a portfolio. Is there any way to make this computation simpler and doable?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Could there possibly be an error in your `for` loop? `while (k <- 4) {...}`. Maybe you meant `while (k == 4) {...}`? What you currently have is an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! good catch. Now it seems work.